# Add click event to CommandButton

Tags: excel, vba, button

I'm trying to add an onClick event programmatically to a CommandButton in VBA. I don't want the CommandButton to be associated with a form because in the end the sheet should look something like this:

[image]

I already have a class module called **boardButton** with an event that should be triggered when the button is clicked:

```
Public WithEvents button As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub button_Click()
    MsgBox "You've just clicked the button"
End Sub
```

And a sub, also declared in a class module, to create the button:

```
Private Sub AddButton(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal column As Integer)
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, column), Cells(row, column))
    
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=t.Left, Top:=t.Top, width:=t.width, height:=t.height)
    Set createdButton = btn.Object
    createdButton.Caption = ""
    createdButton.BackColor = RGB(121, 195, 232)
    
    Dim gameBoardButton As New boardButton
    Set gameBoardButton.button = createdButton
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that the event isn't triggered whenever I click any of the buttons. There are no errors, and I've tried with some other code inside the event sub. I don't know if the way I'm creating the button is the correct way and if that's the reason why the click event isn't being triggered.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next approach:

1. Place the next declaration **on top of a standard module** (in the declaration area):

```
Private gameBoardButton(0) As New boardButton
```

2. Please use the next adapted `Sub`:

```
Private Sub AddButton(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal column As Integer)
    Dim t as Range, btn as OleObject, createdButton as Object, i as Long
    If Ubound(gameBoardButton) = 0 then
       i = 0
    Else
       Redim Preserve gameBoardButton(ubouond(gameBoardButton) + 1)
       i = ubouond(gameBoardButton) + 1
    End If
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, column), Cells(row, column))
    
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=t.Left, Top:=t.Top, width:=t.width, height:=t.height)
    Set createdButton = btn.Object
    createdButton.Caption = ""
    createdButton.BackColor = RGB(121, 195, 232)
    
    Set gameBoardButton(i).button = createdButton
End Sub
```

3. Use your class as it is.

Basically you should declare an array variable at the module level and fill it during buttons creation. Then, it is good to crate the habit of declaring all used variables.

The code is  not tested, but this is the basic idea. If you face any error, do  not hesitate to mention it and ask for help...

Comment: so, both the declaration and the sub should be in a module instead of a class module? and if so, why is that?

Comment: @codingandstuff Because VBA usually uses code modules (standard, sheets, forms). The class module is only necessary to offer the possibility to allocate the same event for more objects. In such a case, buttons. **Did you try the above recommended scenario**? Should I understand that all the code you show was placed in a class module, or class modules?

Comment: the code that's on the sub is on a class module, that was why I asked the question, but I'll rearrange in order to try your version, it looks good. I'll give feedback when I have something, thanks for the help

Comment: @codingandstuff  I could see "I already have a class module called boardButton" and then "And some code to create the button which I'm doing in a sub:" I couldn't imagine that it belongs to a class, too. It is possible to create objects in a class, but in your specific case, no need to do it. You can call the sub in discussion as many time you need (from a sheet code module, standard module, form etc.) without any preliminary declaration, it will create buttons and allocate the event using the simple class you have.

Comment: on a standard module it worked like a charm! I've been stuck in this for a couple of days, thank you so much for your help!